# Is it possible (any built in function especially) to make only *some* of the text in a textbox editable in VB6?

Tags: textbox, vb6

Right now my company is asking me to analyze using a textbox that we use already for generic comments in Visual Studio 2015 VB6. They want to include some sort of tag to indicate something in that textbox, lets say *tag* or *no tag*.

Basically, if Condition 1 is true, I want to know if I can have *tag* appear at the beginning of the textbox string, and still be able to change everything after this tag, but leave the tag there and undeletable, not able to mess it up, keep it at the beginning of the string.

I'm thinking to have a boolean that represents if the tag is there. If it is true, and the tag is 5 characters, I can handle all the user interactions with events.

Ex. User trying to backspace all the way through tag. If boolean is true, then I can check the index at every keypress or maybe keydown etc and if the index is 5 then ignore the delete. Also Every time we enter that text box, through tabbing, or clicking, manually (if that boolean is true) set the cursor position TO 5, so they can only enter after.

There are more scenarios, like if the user highlights part of the tag and further text and tries to delete etc.

I need to do more thinking on this if I need to do it this way to nail it down, but I feel like it is technically possible, although kinda specific and it seems a little silly.

**Is there a more elegant solution? 
 Am I allowed to ask, if you all would bother going down this route (too bug prone, bad coding practice?, not good for future coders?) , or just suggesting a label nearby instead? (since that question may be opinion based)**

This is my first question. Please feel free to give me feedback, if I didn't put enough work into it I'll understand, or If I left out vital details or it doesn't make sense let me know.  I know I didn't show specific code for handling this. I'm more concerned with the general idea and if I need to step back and take a completely different approach.

Comment: You might want to create a user control. You could put two textboxes one above the other inside a picturebox. The top textbox is locked, the bottom is editable

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by VS 2015-VB6 - they're totally different animals.  I don't use VB.Net, but in VB6, the way I'd approach this is to capture each character (using the KeyPress event), and explicitly format the contents of the text box.  Of course, this means you need to handle backspace, delete, insert, and perhaps ^A, ^X, ^C, and ^V yourself, but it's really not too difficult.  You can do all of your logic based upon the current contents of the text box (including the .SelStart and .SelLength properties).

Comment: "Visual Studio 2015 VB6" doesn't make sense. Either you are using VB.NET (in VS 2015) or you are using VB6 (from the 1990s). Or if you are using both, perhaps, please mention what programming you are doing where.

Comment: The broad outline of your proposed solution sounds reasonable to me - a flag to control the behavior, and then special checks to avoid changes to the protected text substring. But if you have more freedom to pick another control - or invent a usercontrol - that might be a much more maintainable and functional solution.

Comment: Ok, so it is VB.NET (in VS 2015), not VB6 then, my mistake. Thank you for the answers.

@ Mark Moulding, this is what I imagine I'll end up doing, if I don't have the freedom for my own user control, since the control they are using is already custom. I did not consider being able to make my own user control until now either.

Answer (score 0):

You could check the text length of the tag since it is placed in the beginning of the string and allow edits only if the current cursor position in the textbox is larger than the tag length.